# Outlook Using a Reply Template and fwd to a Distribution List

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I'm trying to create a VBA macro in Outlook that when an email from a certain address is received, ammend the original email with a reply template and fwd it to a DL .

So far this is what I got :

```
Sub B1(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 'Reply with template
Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem

'This sends a response back using a template
Set oRespond = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\Appdata1\Roaming   \Microsoft\Templates\Request.oft")

With oRespond
.Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
.Subject = "Request for Approval - " & Item.Subject
.HTMLBody = oRespond.HTMLBody & vbCrLf & _
          "---- original message below ---" & vbCrLf & _
           Item.HTMLBody & vbCrLf



.Send

End With
Set oRespond = Nothing
End Sub
```

This doesn't seem to work at all, ha! It worked for a while except the ammending part, then I started tinkering but after that it stopped working altogether.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, are you getting any error?

Comment: It is not doing anything !!! Originally it was working and i started editing it and stopped working altogether ...

Answer (score 0):

Try Deleting the rule and recreate it...

*Code Tested on 2010 Outlook*

```
Option Explicit
Sub B1(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 'Reply with template
    Dim oRespond As Outlook.MailItem
    'This sends a response back using a template
    Set oRespond = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("D:\Appdata1\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Request.oft")

    With oRespond
        .Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress

        .Subject = "Request for Approval - " & Item.Subject

        .HTMLBody = oRespond.HTMLBody & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "---- original message below ---" & vbCrLf & Item.HTMLBody & vbCrLf

        .Display
'        .Send
    End With

    Set oRespond = Nothing
End Sub
```